# While registering a new user the username has to store in multiple tabels

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to php and sql.

I am trying to store the username value in multiple tables at a time when a new user registered.

Here is the screenshot of the table how it is storing. [It is the screen shot of database table how it storing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDPiY.png)

I want the username has to store perfectly along with the other values.

I used a very worst code to store the values at a time in the tables.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$name', '$username', '$email', '$pass', '$gender', '$profile_pic', '$date', '$vkey', '', '0', '0', 'no', ',', '0')");
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO profilepage1 (username) VALUES('$username')");
$query3 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO profilepage2 (username) VALUES('$username')");
```

It is a very bad approach. So please help me to find out the right one

Please help me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is through relational database building.

It is not efficient to have one username stored across multiple tables, instead:

1. Have a [primary key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) set on ID field that [auto increments](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).
2. On the table (table 2) where you need the username, use the user_id to define which user it is. Then create a [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) that connects to the user_id of table 1.

You should look into [Normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html). This is important for SQL efficiency.

When you're using PHP to pull the data, you can use the user's ID to get all their information across multiple tables.

Comment: No problem @SriNikhil - if you found it helpful i'd appreciate a vote up and if your question is answered you can press the tick :) Thank you!